# Book for representation and character theory.

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, representation-theory, finite-fields

Please suggest me elementary  book for representation and character theory of finite group  over finite fields.

Comment: @lisyarus thanks for edit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not aware of any book about representation theory that is geared solely towards finite fields. However, I found the book of Clausen and Baum, ''Fast Fourier Transforms'', very interesting. It goes in the direction mentioned. Clausen is coming from representation theory.

Comment: I will check the book....Bibliography of this may be helpful...